# Saving array in Oracle db

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I need to save an array in a column. I'm currently creating a type as VARRAY and using that which works properly. However when I query the table IN PYTHON (it works fine on the db), that array field is not able to be converted to a python array.

I have tried changing the type from the sql query in the python script but nothing works

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE params_array IS VARRAY(25) of number(25);

create TABLE dependencies 
(
    job_name varchar2(15),
    parameters params_array,
    function_name varchar2(225)
    )

Select parameters from dependencies:
```

expected results:

([10,10])

actual:

(cx_Oracle.Object SYS.PARAMS_ARRAY at 0x7fd9620d02b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an Oracle collection object to a Python list within `cx_Oracle`, use the [`.aslist()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/object_type.html#Object.aslist) method:

```
>>> c = conn.cursor()     
>>> for row in c.execute("SELECT parameters FROM dependencies"):
...     print(row[0].aslist())
...
[10, 20]
```

---

Finally, *really* don't create objects in the `SYS` schema, as you have evidently done with your `PARAMS_ARRAY` type.  This can interfere with the running of the Oracle database.  Oracle can also refuse to support you if you've been creating objects in this schema. The same is probably true for any other schemas built-in to the database.